# session timeout message popup before 5mins of actual session timeout?

Tags: c#, javascript

I need to show a timeout popup window 5 mins before the session timeout. So far I have got

```
<script type="text/javascript">

       function Timeout(intMilsec) {
               setTimeout("window.focus(); alert('Your session will timeout in 5
minutes')", intMilliseconds);
       }
</script>
```

And in c#

```
 if(Session["id"] != null)
  {

      int time = (Session.Timeout - 5) * (60 * 1000);
      Img.Attributes.Add("onload", "Timeout(" +time + ");");
  }
  else
      Img.Attributes.Remove("onload");
```

The popup not showing up before 5mins and never. I need to know if I am missing any settings

Comment: But the popup not showing up before 5mins and never. I need toknow if I am missing any settings.

Comment: Please show what actual javascript is generated by your c# code (you can usually see it by looking at view/source in the browser).  Somewhere in your page, you need a call to `Timeout(5 * 60 * 1000)` to actually set the timer for 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand why you used the image's onload event, but anyway...

You can use `Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(string), "SessionTimeout", "setTimeout(" + time + ")", true);` to call a script on the page loading.

Comment: But do i need to make any changes to make the popup appear just before 5 minutes? Because it's not showing a popup.

Comment: If you have to change something, that would be the javascript. That code is only to write a call to your popup script.

Answer (score 0):

Is your JavaScript working? Have you tried it separately? I tried the exact same code you posted and it didn't work. Try this one:

```
function Timeout(intMilsec) {
    setTimeout(function() { alert('Your session will timeout in 5 minutes'); }, intMilsec);​​​​​​​​​​​​
}
```